# Library 'GameAssembly' not found (2022.3.6f1 silicon, iOS 17.0, Xcode15.0.1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode15, ios17

I'm new to the iOS build process.

I have a Unity project version 2022.3.6f1 silicon to build and deploy on my test iPhone.
I recently updated to Xcode version 15.0.1 (15A507) due to the iOS 17 upgrade.

When I try to build with Xcode, I get an error:

Showing All Messages
Build target UnityFramework of project Unity-iPhone with configuration ReleaseForRunning | SDK iOS 17.0

Link UnityFramework(arm64) 0.1 seconds
Ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
Library 'GameAssembly' not found
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have searched this forum for a solution.
Some have fixed this type of problem by using an editor postprocessor script.(https://forum.unity.com/threads/lin...1-lts-to-unity-editor-2022-3-5f1-lts.1462130/).
I have added the same line of code but it seems to make no difference.

[PostProcessBuild(2000)]

```
public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject)

{

    if (buildTarget != BuildTarget.iOS)

        return;



    PBXProject project = new PBXProject();



    string projectPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

    project.ReadFromFile(projectPath);



    string targetGuid = project.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();

    foreach (string configName in project.BuildConfigNames())

    {

         string configGuid = project.BuildConfigByName(targetGuid, configName);

        project.SetBuildPropertyForConfig(configGuid, "SDKROOT", "iphoneos");

    }



    project.WriteToFile(projectPath);
```

}

Last time I build with Xcode with Unity project 2021.3.0f1 silicon, the GameAssembly doesn't exist in the Xcode project, so I switched the current project (2022.3.6f1) into 2021.3.0f1 and I can see no GameAssembly in the products folder(and Targets) but when building on Xcode,
it shows the similar error:

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Has anyone experienced this?
I am hoping to get some tips on this.

Comment: I had not yet checked the hidden logs in the error, therefore I could not explicitly know what the problem was.
I needed to add an Object-C file to integrate with a specific feature. Case closed.